# Sed/Awk - pull lines between pattern x and y

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've got some large CSV files where I'd like to extract all data between Line X that includes pattern 'x' and Line Y that includes pattern 'y'

For example:

```
other_data
Header
data
data
data
Footer
other_data
```

I want to be able to pipe everything between (and including) Header -> Footer to a new file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `awk` it's pretty straightforward:

```
awk '/Header/ { show=1 } show; /Footer/ { show=0 }'
```

Basically keep state in a variable named `show`. When we hit the Header we turn it on, Footer we turn it off. While it's on, the `show` rule executes the default action of printing the record.

Comment: +1 as this is THE right answer as it is easily enhanced to cover situations where you want to print the first line or the last line or both lines or anything else you want to do. The solutions using /start/,/end/ ranges while slightly briefer fall apart at the slightest requirements change - that pattern makes solutions to trivial problems slightly briefer but solutions to non-trivial problems MUCH more lengthy and complex or require a re-write to this style.

Answer (score 19):

It's pretty straightforward in sed:

```
sed -n '/Header/,/Footer/p'
```

or

```
sed '/Header/,/Footer/!d'
```

Comment: Works just as well as AWK, thank you. I'll give the accepted to Fatal since he got here first, but thank you for this. Here's a +1

Comment: I found the first option (the `/p` ending) to take 1/4 the time as the awk solution. The second option (`/!d`) took the same amount of time as awk. In a big file, it starts to matter.

Comment: This also works when delimiter is the same. The `awk` version only works when they are different.

Comment: @akostadinov since we don't know what the expected behavior is when the delimiter is the same you can't say that either solution works or doesn't work. Similarly for if both delimiters occur on the same line and/or the whole input is a single line and/or if one delimiter is a substring of the other and/or contains regexp metachars and/or there can be different numbers of start vs end delimiters, and/or any of a hundred other things that are not what this question was about.

Comment: @EdMorton, `sed` behavior is very clearly explained under section `Addresses` in `man sed`. It matched my expected behavior so I thought it is relevant enough to put a note about it. Not sure what's bothering you.

Comment: Yes but that's YOUR expected behavior for some problem that YOU are trying to solve. It's not the problem the OP was trying to solve, nor is it the problem that everyone is trying to solve so declaring script A "works" but script B doesn't "work" makes no sense as there is no absolute "works", different solutions work for different problems which all have their own required behavior. Like you, I thought it relevant enough to put a note about it, not sure why you think something has to be bothering me to do so.

Comment: Do I have to separate you two?

Answer (score 11):

Another way with `awk`:

```
awk '/Header/,/Footer/' file
Header
data
data
data
Footer
```

Just redirect the output to save in a newfile:

```
awk '/Header/,/Footer/' file > newfile
```

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the best. +1.

Comment: I'm curious: is there a "from Header until end of file" using that kind of pattern? (It's very easy using the top awk solution, but wondering if there is a "end of file" marker, instead of "/Footer/")

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/^Header/,/^Footer/w new_file' file
```

Comment: This does work, but also redirects the whole of the original file to stdout. This also makes it hard to use with pipes.