# awk/sed: matching pattern between files and printing everything between matches

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I'm trying to combine the topics of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388825/grep-awk-or-sed-print-lines-in-one-file-matching-patterns-in-another-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769411/sed-awk-pull-lines-between-pattern-x-and-y) question, i.e. matching each string/line in `File2` with its occurrence (each string only occurs once) in `File1` while printing the whole line that it occurs on in `File2`, while also printing the lines between each match (i.e. the sequence in `File2`).

File1

```
>GAXI01000525.151.1950 Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Holozoa;Metazoa (Animalia);Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Arthropoda;Hexapoda;Ellipura;Collembola;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
CCUGGUUGAUCCUGCCAGUAGUCAUAUGCUUGUCUCAAA
GAUUAAGCCAUGCAUGUCUAAGUUCAAGCAAAAAUAAAG
ACCGCGAAUGGCUCAUUAUAUCAGUUAUGGUUCCUUAGA
ACUUACUACUUGGAUAACUGUGGUAAUUCUAGAGCUAAU
>GAXI01000526.151.1950 Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Holozoa;Metazoa (Animalia);Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Arthropoda;Hexapoda;Ellipura;Collembola;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
CCUGGUUGAUCCUGCCAGUAGUCAUAUGCUUGUCUCAAAGAU
UAAGCCAUGCAUGUCUAAGUUCAAGCAAAAAUAAAGUGAAAC
>GAXI01005455.1.1233 Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Flavobacteriia;Flavobacteriales;Flavobacteriaceae;Chryseobacterium;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
CUUUCGAAAGGAAGAUUAAUACCCCAUAACAUA
>GAXI01006199.29.1525 Bacteria;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiales;Simkaniaceae;Candidatus Rhabdochlamydia;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
AGAAUUUGAUCUUGGUUCAGAUUGAAUGCUGG
UGCAAGUCGAACGAAGCUAGAGGGCAACCUCU
```

File2

```
>GAXI01000525.151.1950
>GAXI01006199.29.1525
```

What I have so far:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $1 in a' file2 file1 > output
```

which gives:

```
>GAXI01000525.151.1950 Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Holozoa;Metazoa (Animalia);Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Arthropoda;Hexapoda;Ellipura;Collembola;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
>GAXI01006199.29.1525 Bacteria;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiales;Simkaniaceae;Candidatus Rhabdochlamydia;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
```

I would like this:

```
>GAXI01000525.151.1950 Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Holozoa;Metazoa (Animalia);Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Arthropoda;Hexapoda;Ellipura;Collembola;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
CCUGGUUGAUCCUGCCAGUAGUCAUAUGCUUGUCUCAAA
GAUUAAGCCAUGCAUGUCUAAGUUCAAGCAAAAAUAAAG
ACCGCGAAUGGCUCAUUAUAUCAGUUAUGGUUCCUUAGA
ACUUACUACUUGGAUAACUGUGGUAAUUCUAGAGCUAAU
>GAXI01006199.29.1525 Bacteria;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiales;Simkaniaceae;Candidatus Rhabdochlamydia;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
AGAAUUUGAUCUUGGUUCAGAUUGAAUGCUGG
UGCAAGUCGAACGAAGCUAGAGGGCAACCUCU
```

The original files contain thousands of rows so the fastest possible solution is appreciated, either awk, sed or anything else...

Comment: IMHO scientists could get faster and better results using tools that are designed for their work. Using tools like https://metacpan.org/release/BioPerl and/or https://metacpan.org/release/FAST surely allows more effectively reach the goals...

Comment: Surely, though I'm not doing this types of queries on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jO: Try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1];next} ($0 ~ /^>/){Q=""} ($1 in A){Q=1} Q{print}' file2  file1
```

**EDIT:** Adding an explanation too here for solution now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR        ##### This condition will be TRUE when only file2 is being read. where FNR and NR are the awk's in-built keywords FNR and NR both shows number of lines in a Input_file only difference between them FNR gets RESET when it reads next file and NR keep on increase it's values till all files get read successfully.
{A[$1];             ##### creating an array named A whose index is $1 first field of file2.
next}               ##### putting next will skip all the further statements.
                    ##### All further mentioned statements will be executed in file1 only.
($0 ~ /^>/)         ##### checking if any line is starting with > in file1
{Q=""}              ##### Making variable named Q as nullified.
($1 in A)           ##### Checking if current line's $1 is coming into array A, if yes then do following.
{Q=1}               ##### If current $1 is coming into array A then make variable Q's value to 1.
Q                   ##### Check if Q's value is NOT NULL then do following.
{print}             ##### print the lines whenever above condition is TRUE which has Q's value is NOT NULL.
' file2  file1      ##### Mentioning Input_files file2 and file1 here.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{d[$1]; next}/^>/{f=0}$1 in d{f=1}f' file2 file1
```

you get

```
>GAXI01000525.151.1950 Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Holozoa;Metazoa (Animalia);Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Arthropoda;Hexapoda;Ellipura;Collembola;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
CCUGGUUGAUCCUGCCAGUAGUCAUAUGCUUGUCUCAAA
GAUUAAGCCAUGCAUGUCUAAGUUCAAGCAAAAAUAAAG
ACCGCGAAUGGCUCAUUAUAUCAGUUAUGGUUCCUUAGA
ACUUACUACUUGGAUAACUGUGGUAAUUCUAGAGCUAAU
>GAXI01006199.29.1525 Bacteria;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiae;Chlamydiales;Simkaniaceae;Candidatus Rhabdochlamydia;Tetrodontophora bielanensis (giant springtail)
AGAAUUUGAUCUUGGUUCAGAUUGAAUGCUGG
UGCAAGUCGAACGAAGCUAGAGGGCAACCUCU
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's:.*:/^&/bb:' file2 | sed -e ':a' -f - -e 'd;:b;n;/^>/ba;bb' file1
```

Transform file2 into the matches to be printed from file1, otherwise delete the non-matches.

Use two invocations of sed. The first uses file2 to create regexp to match, the second the framework to print lines following a match to the next start of record or end of file.