# Find and return blocks of lines containing a string

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a big file of the following type:

```
key = asbh
some
lines
of
**text**

key = kafeia
some
more
**text**
and
additionally
more
**text**
and
more

key = lklfh
this
is
another
block
```

Note (if important): the line of 'key' never contains the string of interest ('text').

I call a block all the lines between one line starting with "key" and the next such line (so in this example, 3 blocks). I would like to return all blocks containing the string 'text'.
i.e. desired output:

```
key = asbh
some
lines
of
**text**

key = kafeia
some
more
**text**
and
additionally
more
**text**
and
more
```

I tried multiple things and I hope I am in the right direction, but can't seem to get it working.
These are my attempts:

1. `less myfile.txt | sed -n '/key/,/text/p' | less`

   I believe this may start with the first time it sees 'key' and just keeps going (so returns a lot of irrelevant blocks) until it sees 'text'somewhere and stops.
   This is inspired by a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769411/sed-awk-pull-lines-between-pattern-x-and-y) but that does not have the condition of pulling multiple blocks, nor of matching pattern inside blocks.
2. `less myfile.txt | grep -Pzl '(?s)^key([^key]|\n)*text' | less`

   I thought this may be better and if I could get it to work, I could probably extend it as it currently attempts to only get the text between key and text (and not until the next key).
3. I tried understanding how if statements work, particularly in view of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or/38972737#38972737), but I am a novice in unix, so if someone could explain, I would be very grateful.

Comment: It is better to use a language like Python or at least a bash script file (which allows more commands to be written).
Do you want to suggest a python/bash-script solution?

Comment: Is it acceptable to take all lines starting from `key` and stopping at next blank line instead of stopping at next key?

Comment: if `awk` is your option, pleae try
`awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '/^key/ && /text/' myfile.txt`.

Comment: As an aside, that's a magnificent [useless use of `less`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, I can stop at the blank line instead.

Comment: @tripleee, do you mean the less at the start? this is how they told me to read a file and it stuck I guess. For the last less, sorry, I was just checking what comes out in the end.

Comment: The usual antipattern is `cat foo | grep bar` when you can say `grep bar foo` or `grep bar <foo` and the `cat` doesn't do anything useful. Using `less` instead of `cat` is doubly wrong because `less` is specifically a tool for interactively inspecting the contents of a file.

Comment: That means the comment from @tshiono should work pretty well and be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^key/!{H;$!d};x;/text/p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

If a line does not begin `key`, append it to the hold space and delete unless it is the last line.

Otherwise, swap to the hold space and if the collection matches `text`, print it.

N.B. The end-of-file condition naturally drops through to the matching condition. The hold/pattern space flip-flops as and when the `key` matches.

Comment: Thank you! Worked. Initially, I tried re-working using this very helpful sed tutorial (for anyone interested): https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
One thing I don't undersand (although it works!) is how is the statement organised. This is the extent of my understanding: /matching string/ if not a match, i.e. !, do {append to hold, delete something?}; if a match swap the hold space (to print later) / condition stands here but not sure how it works / print if the condition is satisfied
In particular, is this some general syntax if I had conditions or just to match a specific string?

Comment: To see the flow of the program apply the `--debug` option and match up the patten/hold spaces with the input lines.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial with `awk`'s "paragraph" mode, since you have a blank line separating blocks.

```
$: awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' /text/ file
key = asbh
some
lines
of
**text**

key = kafeia
some
more
**text**
and
additionally
more
**text**
and
more
```

I added the explicit newline back; note this will append one at end of file even if it wasn't present.

Explanation:

`-v` sets `v`ariables in the run.
`RS=` sets the `R`ecord `S`eparator empty, enabling "paragraph mode" that reads until it sees a *blank* line and calling all that it read (yes, the whole block) one "record".
`ORS=$'\n\n'` sets the `O`utput `R`ecord `S`eparator to *two* newlines, adding the blank line *back* after the paragraph-mode read removed it.
`/text/` scans the "record" of several lines for your trigger string. If it returns true, since I didn't provide any other code to execute, it prints that block.
(Note that since it was such a simple check I didn't need quotes around it; I opted to leave them off to reduce noise. YMMV.)

## Addendum

Just noticed tshiono's comment hours ahead of me.
Amended my own accordingly - Credit where due.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Will update. I just kinda like the $'\n\n'. No real reason.

Comment: A valid reason not to do it if unnecessary. Also - one less character to type, lol

Answer (score 0):

For code cleanliness and readability, I suggest using Python or a bash script file.

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

blocks = []
current_block = []

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('key'):
        # Check if the current block contains 'text'
        if any('text' in block_line for block_line in current_block):
            blocks.extend(current_block)
        current_block = [line]
    else:
        current_block.append(line)

# Check the last block in case it ends with 'text'
if any('text' in block_line for block_line in current_block):
    blocks.extend(current_block)

# Print or use the blocks as needed
for block in blocks:
    print(block.strip())
```

If you insist on doing this operation in one line, you can also use this code:

```bash
awk '/^key/ { if (block ~ /text/) print block; block=""; } { block = block $0 RS } END { if (block ~ /text/) print block }' file.txt
```

I checked this method on several files and it was correct. I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: The one-liner didn't work for me and I couldn't understand how the structure of it works (things like global organisation of {},$0, RS), so I couldn't re-work it. Python I don't want to use as for big files (as is mine) it's probably best to work directly.

Answer (score 0):

Bash may not be the best tool for this, but it can certainly do the job. The following snippet has no error handling whatsoever; it’s just an example that happens to work with the input from the question.

```bash
read_blocks() {
  local -r needle="$1"
  local -n _blocks="$2"  # declare -A
  local -n _keys="$3"    # declare -a
  local -i needle_seen=0
  local line key='UNSET'
  _blocks=()
  _keys=()
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" = 'key = '* ]]; then
      ((needle_seen)) && _keys+=("$key") || unset '_blocks["$key"]'
      ((needle_seen = 0)) || :
      key="${line#key = }"
    else
      [[ "$line" = *"$needle"* ]] && ((++needle_seen)) || :
      _blocks["$key"]+="$line"$'\n'
    fi
  done
  ((needle_seen)) && _keys+=("$key") || unset '_blocks["$key"]'
}

declare -A blocks
declare -a keys
read_blocks 'text' 'blocks' 'keys' < /path/to/input

for key in "${keys[@]}"; do
  printf 'key = %s\n' "$key"
  printf '%s' "${blocks["$key"]}"
done
```

In case the order of blocks does **not** need to be preserved, then you can ditch the `keys` array entirely and simply iterate over `${!blocks[@]}` while writing the output.